# Minimum cost path from first column to last column with some twist

Tags: python-3.x

finding minimum cost path from first column to last column (but the catch is you can choose only continuous element in rows)

for ex 1 -

```
        [[1,7,1],
        [2,1,3],
        [3,2,3]]
```

answere -      2   ( from row 2)   +    1   (from row 2)   +   1     (from row 1)=4 -right answere

you can't take - 1   (from row 1)+1   (from row 2)     +1    (from row 1) =3 (wrong answere)

```
 [[1,7,1],
  [2,1,3],
  [3,2,3]]
```

**(because after coming from row1 to row 2 you cant jump back to row1 that makes discontinuity in row 1)

ex 2-

```
     [[1,1,2],
     [3,1,2],
     [1,4,1]]
```

answere-      1 (from row 1)  +   1  (from row 2)  +1   (from row 3)=   3 (right answere)

Comment: What does it have to do with anything?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately this requires far more detail to understand the problem you're experiencing! Nested arrays can mean many things and are not specific to your problem. What have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)